Is there a difference between social status and social standing?
These two terms are used seemingly interchangeably in sociology and psychology articles. Are these interchangeable or is there some technical difference between the two?
As an example, in measuring socioeconomic status, "Rossi recruited a convenience sample of N=146 white adults
in Baltimore and asked them to rate the social standing of households described in terms of
spouses’ occupations, incomes, and ethnicities"
And in the same article, you see "Relatedly, without sound measurement of SES it is impossible to understand the
intergenerational change of social status over time."
In this way these terms are used seemingly interchangeably and I wanted to know if there's any difference here between them
